# Current obtained using half wave rectifier

Tags: electric-circuits

In a transformer the voltage in the secondary coil is 180 degrees out of phase with the voltage in primary coil. So the current should also be out of phase. However in all the graphs I have come across in books the current obtained in the secondary coil ( after half wave rectification ) is in the same phase as the current provided by the ac coil ( the primary coil) for each positive half cycle of the ac source voltage. Why is this so? I am a bit confused with the graph.[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of such a graph?

Comment: Please  see my edited question with the graph

Comment: A half wave rectifier is not a transformer. It's a diode. As such, the voltage and current make sense.

Comment: I think the first graph represents the voltage in the secondary coil. I honestly don't know why everyone usually draw schemes  of half wave rectifiers with transformers at the input (maybe it is their main application) but you can think of it as a normal ac voltage generator. With those graphs they only want to show what a rectifier does to an input wave

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any transformer.

Comment: Yeah I guess the diode is being used as rectifier. But it is connected to the secondary coil of a transformer and the ac input is connected to the primary coil. ( at least in the diagram in the book). But can u directly use the diode with an ac source without a transformer? I don’t know really.

Comment: You only need the transformer if the incoming voltage is not what you want.